# Convert comma separated text to a list of numbers

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI, I have created a DAX query created with a var giving comma-separated text using `CONCATENATEX` function.

Output like

```
Var = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
```

Now I want to search this var into my table column with syntax

```
Table[col] in {var}.
```

It is throwing an error.

I even tried converting the column to string with syntax

```
Convert(table[col], string)  in {var}
```

The error is removed but the data doesn't match with column data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this Power BI community thread](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-how-split-a-string-by-delimiter-into-a-list-or-array/td-p/559597) that is essentially the same question.

The solution is to convert the string into a path object.

Here's the code from the link:

```
Measure 3 =
VAR mymeasure =
    SUBSTITUTE ( [Measure], ",", "|" )
VAR Mylen =
    PATHLENGTH ( mymeasure )
VAR mytable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, mylen ),
        "mylist", VALUE ( PATHITEM ( mymeasure, [Value] ) )
    )
VAR mylist =
    SELECTCOLUMNS ( mytable, "list", [mylist] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( Table1 ), Table1[ID] IN mylist )
```

---

There's a bit of redundancy in the above, so I'd probably condense it a bit and write it like this:

```
SomeMeasureFilteredByVar =
VAR PathVar = SUBSTITUTE ( [Var], ",", "|" )
VAR VarList =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( PathVar ) ),
        "Item", VALUE ( PATHITEM ( PathVar, [Value] ) )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( [SomeMeasure], 'Table'[ID] IN VarList )
```

---

**Edit:** To just create a calculated table, you can skip the last step:

```
TableFromString =
VAR PathVar = SUBSTITUTE ( "1,2,3,4,5,6", ",", "|" )
RETURN
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( PathVar ) ),
        "Item", VALUE ( PATHITEM ( PathVar, [Value] ) )
    )
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

Note that it is *not possible* to create a calculated table that is dynamically responsive to report filters and slicers. Materialized calculated tables are only calculated once when the data loads, not every time you adjust a filter or slicer.

Therefore, you can use a measure in the table instead of the string `"1,2,3,4,5,6"` but the table output will be the same regardless of what the measure returns within different filter contexts.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, I tried and found that the code is not throwing and error and returning a value. But if I want to see my var string mymeasure  into calculated table column rows than what should be my approach. I tried your code and tried to return list variable to a calculated table, but it's giving me many unnecessary values along.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, just skip the last step.

Comment: Thanks Alexis! If the calculated table cannot work dynamically on filters. I guess I have to check for other approaches.